# declare events in javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Normally when I working with javascript in object literal style I load events for page such way:

```
var myObject = {
    button: $('button'),
    init: function() {
        button.on('click', $.proxy(this.myMethod, this));
    },
    myMethod: function(event) {
        alert('Hello');
    }
};
myObject.init();
```

Now I would like to have array of events in my config property like this

```
var myObject = {
    bindActions: [
        $('#employee_data').on('click', $.proxy(this.myMethod, this))
    ],
    init: function() {
        // here I assume I need to do something like this 
        // to load all events from this.bindActions
        // this.bindActions.forEach(function(action) {

        //     ?????? 

        // });

    },
    myMethod: function(event) {
        alert('Hello');
    };
};
myObject.init();
```

Please help me figure out how I can attach this events in loop, with some explanation?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason why you want to iterate over an array (maybe finer control of which events are bound and when?), you'd be better off turning `bindActions` in to a function itself that's executed when you run `myObject.init()`, like this;

```
var myObject = {
    bindActions: function(){
        $('#employee_data').on('click', $.proxy(this.myMethod, this));

        // bind as many as you want here
        //$('#employee_data').on('..', ...)
    },
    init: function() {
        // bind all events in bindActions when init() is executed
        this.bindActions(); 
    },
    myMethod: function(event) {
        alert('Hello');
    };
};

myObject.init();
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay but lately I would probably need to add/remove (attach/deattach?) events dynamically to the bindActions[] array so I would like to better understand also how to achieve this on this way